# Unable to configure hierarchical settings with dotnet under IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis, appsettings

For our dotnet application, we have an appsettings.json file using hierarchical settings like:

> "mysection": {  "myproperty": "my secret value" }

This appsettings.json is used for development purpose.

In production mode, we use the Azure Keyvault (as our application is running under Azure)
In the keyvault, the Secret is defined with

> mysection--myproperty

But now, we need to deploy the same webservice under IIS.  We would like to define the secret value under the IIS settings but **mysection--myproperty** or **mysection:myproperty** doesn't work.

Do you have an idea how to set this hierarchy under IIS?

Comment: _In Azure Key Vault, hierarchical keys use -- as a separator. The Azure Key Vault configuration provider automatically replaces -- with a : when the secrets are loaded into the app's configuration._ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration-keys-and-values

Comment: Use `IConfigurationRoot.GetDebugView()` to see how the configuration is wired up: https://andrewlock.net/debugging-configuration-values-in-aspnetcore/

Comment: @abdusco I know that keyvault is using -- as separator.  But I'm looking for a solution with configuration inside IIS

Comment: Oh, you'd use environment variables for that, and they're separated with double underscores `__`

Comment: @abdusco Put your comment as a response, I will validate as the right answer.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using environment variables, subsections need to be separated with double underscores `__`.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables):

> The `:` separator doesn't work with environment variable hierarchical keys on all platforms. `__`, the double underscore, is:
>
> - Supported by all platforms. For example, the `:` separator is not supported by Bash, but `__` is.
> - Automatically replaced by a `:`

That means you need to change `mysection--myproperty` to

```
mysection__myproperty
```

for it to be parsed correctly.

Additionally, you can use [`IConfigurationRoot.GetDebugView()`](https://andrewlock.net/debugging-configuration-values-in-aspnetcore/) to see where a configuration value comes from.